# With flow types, is it possible to auto infer return value for function that takes another function as an argument?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say I have a function that takes a function as an argument and returns another function that takes a value that it passes to the function passed as an argument:

```
const curry = f => x => f(x);
```

Is it possible to type this function using Flow Type in such a way that the return value of `curry` is determined by the function `f` passed in if that function has been typed?

I tried this:

```
const numToStr = (x: number): string => x.toString();
const curry = <F: Function>(f: F): (mixed => *) => (x: mixed): * => f(x);
const curried = curry(numToStr);
```

[link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzGwFcBbAFTgGV8AnMAXjAAoAPALiLICMBTWgJScCtAJbYA5owB8YVgDp81OuInMBAbkw4CYDMVq0AnozAAeAGKcLxbBnyic05lGsCZLDmFKjWvACZCyB5QbJraeIT6hqIBptHGzCQUyoJaWJFg+Ly6TAmx-swAzOFgZeVlQA)

The result of passing the first argument is that the resulting function `curried` has a signature like this:

```
(((x: mixed) => any) | ((x: mixed) => empty))
```

This makes sense, either the result is empty or it's anything. What I'd hoped is that because `numToStr` is typed, that it'd be possible for Flow to understand that `curried` is really `number => string`.

Is there a way to do this that I've missed? If not, can anyone explain why.

Comment: Are you sure you intended to curry a function of only one argument? Usually currying refers to transforming a function of two arguments into a function that takes one argument and returns another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currying *usually* applies to the process of taking a function of two arguments and transforming it into a function of one argument that returns another function of one argument which returns the result.

In Flow it would look like this:

```
const curry = <A, B, C>(f: (A, B) => C): (A => (B => C)) => (x) => (y) => f(x, y);

const prefixNum = (prefix: string, x: number): string => prefix + x.toString();
const prefixed = curry(prefixNum);
const withHello = prefixed("hello ");
const result = withHello(3); // "hello 3"
```

Your version is a bit different. You are transforming a function of one argument into a function of zero arguments. This is more like lazy evaluation than currying: supply all of the arguments but only return a zero-argument function (sometimes called a "thunk"), which actually performs the computation when you call it. The implementation could look like this:

```
const makeLazy = <A, C>(f: A => C): (A => (() => C)) => (x) => () => f(x);
```

It's essentially the definition above, but with one of the types replaced with `()`. This should work how you want it to:

```
const numToStr = (x: number): string => x.toString();
const lazyNumToStr = makeLazy(numToStr);
const thunk = lazyNumToStr(3);
thunk(); // "3"
```

Comment: Good answer. Thank you for correcting my invocation of currying, as well!